# Angular2 Dart - Get Text inside Angular2 Component

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I've got an `item` component which I use inside other components, the item component typically looks like this:

```
<item type="the-type" text="the-text"></item>
```

and is defined like this:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'item',
    template: '...')
class Item {

    @Input() String text = "text-goes-here";    
    @Input() String type = "type-goes-here";

}
```

Now I want to change the `item` so that it has a more natural feel to it:

```
<item type="the-type">the-text</item>
```

Now I want to get the text `the-text` from this component.

I change the `item` component to implement `AfterContentInit` to see if I can somehow capture the text and then use `@ContentChild(String)` to get the String content of the `item` component, but it doesn't seem to work ...

```
@Component(
    selector: 'item',
    //providers: const[String],
    template: '')
class Item implements AfterContentInit {

    @ContentChild(String) String text;
    @Input() String type = "type-goes-here";

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        print("ngAfterContentInit: " + text);
    }

}
```

This gives me a giant stacktrace; `@ContentChild` doesn't seem like the right solution here since it's probably expecting another `@Component` instead of a `String`

All the Angular examples I can find in the docs are using attributes to pass on values and mostly leaves the content part empty and those that does make use of child components, make use of a proper `@Component` child component.

Is it possible to get `the-text` out of `<item>the-text</item>` and if so, how should it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@ContentChild()` or `@ContentChildren()` you can only query for components and directives by passing the type of these components or directives as parameter or you can query for template variables.

If you have

```
<item type="the-type">
  <div #someVar>the-text<div>
</item>`
```

then you can query for the div with

```
@ContentChild('someVar') ElementRef someVar;
```

If you don't want the user of your component to require to wrap the content with an element and add a specific template variable you can use a wrapper element around `<ng-content>`

```
@Component(
    selector: 'item',
    //providers: const[String],
    template: '<div #wrapper><ng-content></ng-content></div>')
class Item implements AfterContentInit {

    @ViewChild('wrapper') ElementRef wrapper;
    @Input() String type = "type-goes-here";

    @override
    ngAfterContentInit() {
        print(wrapper.innerHtml); // or `wrapper.text`
    }
}
```

Not sure yet if this issue will make this easier https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563

Comment: I guess that's why everybody is using attributes then, the alternatives seem horrible :-|

Comment: Yup, it's not optimal and I'm sure they will improve it eventually.