# Angular 2 query for transcluded content in a specific ng-content

Tags: angular

I would like to query my template for transcluded content by accessing one of the `ng-content` tags, preferably by its `select` attribute, without setting a local variable on the element.

Is this possible?

```
<comp>
  <span world>Hello world</span>
</comp>
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <ng-content select="[world]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Comp.ts:

```
@ContentChild('world') world: ElementRef;
```

The above does not work, which was expected since I was merely shooting from the hip.

How can I query the ng-content for its content?

The use case is to check whether content has actually been passed to the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `ng-content` to select your span you would need to add a `world` attribute

```
<comp>
  <span world>Hello world</span>
</comp>
```

You can't use `@ContentChild()` to query for elements without a template variable or a component or directive type.

Perhaps this approach helps [Angular2 Dart - Get Text inside Angular2 Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37630868/angular2-dart-get-text-inside-angular2-component/37631371#37631371)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the attribute in my simple example. That's a bummer, but I guess I'll just have to add a variable then.

Comment: What about the linked answer?

Comment: That uses a variable, so that would be the way? :P

Comment: Sure, but the variable is in the tempalte of `<comp>`, not in the transcluded content (nothing to add by the user of your component).

Comment: Ye that's what I did.